# Remove a key, value from a json object from scala

Tags: json, scala

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._


val jsonObj = JSON.parseFull("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ProductWithLatestPrice\",\"namespace\":\"models\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"isbn\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ku\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"pc\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}},\"default\":[]},{\"name\":\"mpn\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}},\"default\":[]},{\"name\":\"smallDescription\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"longDescription\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"specificationText\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}],\"default\":null}]}")
```

I want to remove the key "smallDescription" and its values from this json without using regex. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work (updated to match nested array/object structures):

```scala
def remove(key: String)(x: Any): Any =
  x match {
    case m: Map[String, _] => m.mapValues(remove(key)) - key
    case l: List[_] => l.map(remove(key))
    case v => v
  }

val jsonObj = JSON.parseFull("…").map(remove("smallDescription"))
```

I would recommend to use a JSON library though, like http://json4s.org/ or http://argonaut.io/.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, Changed it now. Will get back on this.

Comment: Actually, "smallDescription" is not a top level property, its inside the property "fields" as a value which has the list of map. Meaning i have to delete the entire `{"name":"smallDescription","type":["null",{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}],"default":null}` map chunk.